# How to print following empty up side down pattern

Tags: python, ascii-art

I am trying to print this following pattern , But not able to frame logic

**My code :**

```
for i in range(1,row+1):
    if i == 1:
        print(row * '* ')
    elif i<row:
        print( '* ' + ((row - 3) * 2) * ' ' + '*')
        row = row - 1
    else:
        print('*')
```

**Expected output :**

```
* * * * * * * *
*           *
*         *
*       *
*     *
*   *
* *
*
```

**But my code gives me abnormal output :**

```
* * * * * * * * 
*           *
*         *  
*       *    
*
*
*
*
```

Comment: Please explain `((row - 3) * 2)` - what is your intention there?

Comment: You count "i" up and "row" down at the same time until they meet about in the middle.

Comment: @LMD : I was trying on notepad++ to check how many spaces do i need to add to make my second row expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@stacker's answer is nifty but mathematically a little overkill. This should do the trick just as well:

```
row = 8
print(row * '* ')
for i in range(1,row - 1):
    rowlength = (row - i) * 2 - 3
    print('*', end='')
    print(rowlength * ' ', end='')
    print('*')
print('*')
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import math

row = 8;
for i in range(1,row+1):
    if i == 1:
        print(row * '* ')
    elif i<(row * row) / (math.pi / math.sqrt(7)):
        print( '* ' + ((row - 3) * 2) * ' ' + '*')
        row = row - 1
    else:
        print('*')
```

Output:

```
* * * * * * * * 
*           *
*         *
*       *
*     *
*   *
* *
*
```

Answer (score -3):

```
row=10
for i in range(1,row):
    if i == 1:
        print(row * '* ')
    elif i < row:
        print('* ' + (row-2)*2 * ' ' + '*')
        row = row-1
    elif i > row-2:
        print('* ' + (row - 2) * 2 * ' ' + '*')
        row = row - 1
```

Output:

```
* * * * * * * * * * 
*                 *
*               *
*             *
*           *
*         *
*       *
*     *
*   *

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Hope this helps